# HtmlAgilityPack How to get a SELECTED <option> in a <select>

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, getelementbyid

So im trying to get the selected Value from a selectfield.

The Html:

```
<select class= "c_selectfield" id="id_secMode-101" name="secMode-101"><option value="1" >None</option><option value="2" >WPA_PSK_TKIP</option><option value="3" >WPA2_PSK_AES</option><option value="5" SELECTED >WPA2-EAP</option><option value="4"  >WEP</option><option value="7"  disabled>Advanced config</option></select>
```

In this Example WPA2-EAP is selected and i want the Programm to return the Value 5.

My C# function looks like this:

```
        public void Get_Wlan_Settings_Html(HtmlDocument html)
    {

        SSID = html.GetElementbyId("id_Setssid-101").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
        PassKey = html.GetElementbyId("id_wlanMgr_fakePassKey-101").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
        client_user_id = html.GetElementbyId("id_userId-101").GetAttributeValue("value", "");
        eap_PassKey = html.GetElementbyId("id_wlanMgr_fakeEapPwd-101").GetAttributeValue("value", "");

    }
```

the elements i'm getting are in the same html, these work perfectly fine.
But How can i get the selected Values?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected option value for `id_secMode-101` by using XPath.

```
html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//select[@id='id_secMode-101']//*[@selected='selected']").
Attributes["value"].Value;
```

More info regarding [SelectSingleNode](https://html-agility-pack.net/select-single-node).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. If i use it like this:

            `sec_mode = Int32.Parse(html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//select[@id='id_secMode-101']//*[@selected='selected']").
                       Attributes["value"].Value);`

then HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.SelectSingleNode returns null

Comment: Try changing 'selected' to 'SELECTED'

Comment: Nope, still returns null

Answer (score 0):

You can code like this,

```
var selectedValues = html.GetElementbyId("id_secMode-101")
                         .ChildNodes
                         .Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue("selected", string.Empty) == "selected");
```